# Creating view across different databases

Tags: mysql, database, view

If I have database `D1` and database `D2`, and table `T1` under database `D1` and table `T2` under database `D2`, is it possible to create a view of `T1` under database `D2` in MySQL. If so, can you show me the syntax.

Bot databases are on the same machine.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW `D2`.`example` AS SELECT * FROM `D1`.`T1`;
```

Comment: how is that doable if you have different user for each database? do we need to GRANT view to the 'viewing' user? I need to do that but i'm not just there yet. edit: precision -> same host, different users.

Comment: how can I select particular fileds with this? `SELECT D1.T1.F1`?