# How to connect 2 databases in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible connect 2 database in zend framework

`SELECT * from db1. table JOIN SELECT * from db2.table.`

Comment: Which particular Zend_DB features are you currently using then?

Comment: `$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)`

Comment: Hi I am using MYSQL db.

Comment: Hi Richard 

$select->setIntegrityCheck(false) wont work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to your question, may be the solution to you problem.

As seen in [Creating view across different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694601/creating-view-across-different-databases) you can create a view (in a DB) as join of 2 tables in 2 different DBs.

Then you can query that view as normal table